# rails form data not being saved to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am trying to store form data to the database but instead null values are being enterd, what could be the problem?
my view form.html.erb file is

```
  <%= form_for(@cattle_client) do |f| %>
    <% if @cattle_client.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@cattle_client.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cattle_client from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @cattle_client.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :client_name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :client_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :milk %><br>
      <%= f.number_field :milk %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :date %><br>
      <%= f.date_select :date %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

My cattle_clients_controller.rb is

```
    class CattleClientsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_cattle_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /cattle_clients
      # GET /cattle_clients.json
      def index
        @cattle_clients = CattleClient.all
      end

      # GET /cattle_clients/1
      # GET /cattle_clients/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /cattle_clients/new
      def new
        @cattle_client = CattleClient.new
      end

      # GET /cattle_clients/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /cattle_clients
      # POST /cattle_clients.json
      def create
        @cattle_client = CattleClient.new(cattle_client_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @cattle_client.save
            format.html { redirect_to @cattle_client, notice: 'Cattle client was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cattle_client }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @cattle_client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /cattle_clients/1
      # PATCH/PUT /cattle_clients/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @cattle_client.update(cattle_client_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @cattle_client, notice: 'Cattle client was successfully updated.' }
           format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cattle_client }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @cattle_client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /cattle_clients/1
      # DELETE /cattle_clients/1.json
      def destroy
        @cattle_client.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to cattle_clients_url, notice: 'Cattle client was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_cattle_client
          @cattle_client = CattleClient.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def cattle_client_params
          params.require(:cattle_client).permit(:client_name, :milk, :date)
        end
    end
```

And my routes file has

```
     resources :cattle_clients
```

Anyone help me identify what the problem is?

My migrations file is

```
    class CreateCattleClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :cattle_clients do |t|
          t.string :client_name
          t.integer :milk
          t.date :date

          t.timestamps null: false
       end
     end
   end
```

the model is

```
    class CattleClient < ActiveRecord::Base
    end
```

Comment: Post your complete controller file.

Comment: Also your `rails s` log output when saving too.

Comment: Why there is some erb in your controller?? 0_o Anyway, do you have any failing validations in your model?

Comment: Areyou really having `<% end %>` in your `create` method or just a typo?

Comment: Strategy for debugging:  1) look at the params coming though to the controller, in your log file.  Do they look wrong?  Your form is to blame.  2) if they look right, then maybe your controller code is to blame.  In the console, step through line by line with the params from your log file.

Comment: What is the value of `cattle_client_params`?

Comment: You're using `cattle_client_params` but you haven't posted that method. Please do, in case you haven't permitted the params you need.

Comment: I have edited the controller file to make it complete

Comment: Your `form` and `controller` code is correct. Are you having any `attr_accessor` in your model?

Comment: Have not added a thing yet to the model @ Paven

Comment: Scroll to the end of the controller file, the 'cattle_client_params' is defined there @ Matt

Comment: @BARBRA I think we need to see the migrate and model, both the view and controller seem ok. Also, when you @ someone, don't add a space :)

Comment: Have you restarted your server since running the migrates? Could you try creating a `CattleClient` via the console and let us know how that goes? When you submit the form is there any feedback? Anything suspect in the log?

Comment: I ran the migrates, started the server and when i try creating a CattleClient in the form, i fill in the form but on submit, reflects empty column with the options on edit and delete. With no errors btw

Comment: try to print cattle_client_params inside create action ...kindly tell me what you see when the form is submitted....the values in the params?

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit my models file to tool like this

```
  class CattleClient < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :client_name, :milk, :date
  end
```

Thanks for the contributions tho @Matt, Pavan, Max and all the rest, i appreciate alot

Comment: If that was necessary then the error may have been in your strong_params (the `cattle_client_params` method). Very strange, I'd suggest you keep trying to find the problem with the params rather than adding in `attr_accessible` which defeats the point of strong_params.

Comment: Okk,, will try looking into that still, thanx alot for your time @Matt